# Why is graphQL returning multiple nodes inside edges?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

My GraphQL is returning multiple nodes inside edges. I have a JSON on which I am running this graphQL. This has been set up in a Gatsby project.

[This is the JSON](https://jsonblob.com/f684165b-876c-11e9-b0b4-55e8cd7ed47f)

[This is the Schema](https://jsonblob.com/2592ca53-876e-11e9-b0b4-2983a57c9b74)

This is the snapshot of the query I am running inside GraphiQL:
[image]

Moreover, sometimes data come inside the first node and sometimes in second.

The structure of my project has been set up like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: One node per file found under `src/data`

Comment: This might help you https://itnext.io/reading-data-from-a-json-file-with-gatsby-graphql-572b18ab98a

Comment: @ksav Your first comment worked, it is the right answer. Please post it as an answer and I will tick mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. `gatsby-source-filesystem` will create one node for each file found at the specified paths.

> The plugin creates File nodes from files. The various “transformer” plugins can transform File nodes into various other types of data e.g. gatsby-transformer-json transforms JSON files into JSON data nodes

[gatsby-source-filesystem](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/)

If you want to transform the contents of a json file into graphql nodes, look into the `gatsby-transformer-json` plugin. If you want to create json files and subsequent nodes from an existing api try the `gatsby-source-apiserver` plugin.